# select data from multiple tables by matching multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like so:

Table User

```
    +---------+-----------------+
    | UserId  | UserName        |
    +---------+-----------------+
    | 1       | one@test.com    |
    | 2       | two@test.com    |    
    | 3       | three@test.com  |  
    | 4       | four@test.com   |
    +---------+-----------------+
```

Table Employee

```
    +-------------+----------------+------------+----------+---------+
    | EmployeeId  | Email          | Department | Position | Duty    |
    +-------------+----------------+------------+----------+---------+
    | 1           | one@test.com   | Accounting | Manager  | Aproval |
    | 2           | two@test.com   | Accounting | Manager  | NULL    |
    | 3           | three@test.com | Marketing  | Staff    | NULL    |
    | 4           | four@test.com  | Purchasing | Staff    | NULL    |
    +-------------+----------------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Table Authorization

```
    +------------------+----------------+------------+----------+----------+
    | AuhtorizationId  | Level          | Department | Position | Duty     |
    +------------------+----------------+------------+----------+----------+
    | 1                | 1              | Accounting | Manager  | NULL     |
    | 2                | 2              | Marketing  | Staff    | NULL     |
    | 3                | 3              | Purchasing | Staff    | NULL     |
    | 4                | 4              | Accounting | Manager  | Approval |
    +------------------+----------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

How to construct a MySQL query to retrieve UserId, UserName/Email, Level, Department, and Position?

Comment: Your tables are not normalized. There is the same data in "User" and "Employee" tables.

Comment: What are the relationships between your tables? I don't see any obvious foreign keys, so there's no way for example to know which  employee record should be associated with which user record. If you're using Email/UserName and Employee.Position/Authorization.Position to match your records, then you should really have UserId in Employees instead of Email and create a separate table Positions with both Employee and Authorization containing PositionId references to that table instead of strings.

Comment: Yes, the tables are not normalized. Just trying to solve an existing schema by not normalizing them. The first column in each table is primary key. Need to find matches not by foreign key, but using the Department-Position-Duty and Email-UserName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFiddleExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5b49/7)**

```
SELECT 
u.`UserID`, 
u.`UserName`, 
a.`Level`, 
e.`Department`, 
e.`Position` 
FROM `User` u   
  LEFT JOIN `Employee` e
    ON u.`UserId` = EmployeeID 
  LEFT JOIN `Authorization` a 
    ON u.`UserId` = a.`AuhtorizationId`
```

Result:

```
| USERID |       USERNAME | LEVEL | DEPARTMENT | POSITION |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|      1 |   one@test.com |     1 | Accounting |  Manager |
|      2 |   two@test.com |     2 | Accounting |  Manager |
|      3 | three@test.com |     3 |  Marketing |    Staff |
|      4 |  four@test.com |     4 | Purchasing |    Staff |
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctrly all the table relations

```
  SELECT UserID, UserName, Level, Department, Position FROM User   
INNER JOIN Employee ON UserId=EmployeeID INNER JOIN Authorization ON UserId = AuhtorizationId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User.UserID, User.UserName, Authorization.Level, Authorization.Department, Authorization.Position FROM User INNER JOIN Employee ON User.UserId=Employee.EmployeeID INNER JOIN Authorization ON Employee.Department = Authorization.Department WHERE Employee.Position=Authorization.Position AND Employee.Duty=Authorization.Duty
```